# Google Tag Manager script tag update

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a website that uses GTM to fire custom script tags.
Is there a way to know when those scripts was updated/changed on the website itself ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could add a passive listener (important so it doesn't break when GTM doesn't load or is blocked) in your code that is triggered in the custom script tag. Example below requires jquery.

In your custom tag

`$('body').trigger('gtm:customTagFired', {{ data }});`

In your code

`$('body').on('gtm:customTagFired', function(e, data) {
    // do something
});`

Another option would be to use tag sequencing in GTM to fire another custom code snippet.